# Setting up remote debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I need help in setting up remote debugging. Could you please provide me instructions on how to do this? I’m using IntelliJ  IDEA.

I get an error after configuring port and host:

```
Error running liferay: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8080): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed»
```

[image: My configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration looks correctly, so there are two options why it is not working:

1. You try to connect to the wrong debugging port of your server. If you run Tomcat check [JPDA_ADDRESS](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Setting+Up+Tomcat+For+Remote+Debugging) that responsible for debugging mode.
2. You just run your server in not debugging mode. If you use Tomcat start server like this:

   On windows

   `$ catalina.bat jpda start`

   On Linux/Unix

   `$ catalina.sh jpda start`